# insert multiple value to formarray with the same field

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have form that insert commments before creation :
my current code inserts several comments but each time  adds an input field before insert.
I want to insert several values but with the same input field.
this is my form:

```
  this.insertForm = this.fb.group({
  domaine:  ['', [Validators.required]],
  idprblm:  ['', [Validators.required]],
  causeProb:    [  '' , [Validators.required]],

  comments: this.fb.array([])})
```

I want to insert multiple comments before creation this comments have :

```
 get comments() : FormArray {
  return this.editForm.get("comments") as FormArray
}
// create comment
newComment(): FormGroup {
  let a = ""+this.compte.nomEmploye+" "+this.compte.prenomEmploye;
  return this.fb.group({
    date: new FormControl(new Date()),
    contenu:new FormControl(''),
    personne:new FormControl(a)
  })
}
addComment() {
   let a = this.newComme();
   console.log("this is a ",a,typeof(a))
  this.commentaires.push(a);

  this.comments.valueChanges.subscribe( (data) => {
    console.log("comments update :", data ); 
  });
}

//remove Comments
removecomments(i:number) {
  this.comments.removeAt(i);
  console.log("this is comment ",i)
}
```

this is my html code :

```
     <div formArrayName="comments" >
      <div class="card-body"   >
        <div class="input-group mb-2" *ngFor="let comment of comments.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ecrire un commentaire" formControlName="contenu">
        </div>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text" style="border: none;"> <button class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="addComment()">
              <i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i>
            </button></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

that's is what I m looking for :
[image]

Comment: Hallo, Can you please Update the question with complete code to understand the question better. 
For eg: I do not understand where `this.commentaires` comes from and what you do with it. 

Preferably upload it here https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @ArunRajagopal ok check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9mo2jr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the stack link. I can understand what the issues is.

The addComments() method in your code adds a new FormControl therefore many Input fields. I guess what you wanted to do is push comments to a seperate variable. Look at the link below.

URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x7ac4m

Comment: yes that's exactly what I need  , but you used just a formcontrol and you have saved the comments locally, I want to use formarray instead of formcontrol to save this comments with my form in database